# Optimising write  speeds in HDF5 using Pytables

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, hdf5, pytables

The problem is with respect to the writing speed of the computer (10 * 32 bit machine) and the postgresql query performance.I will explain the scenario in detail.

I have data about 80 Gb (along with approprite database indexes in place). I am trying to read it from Postgresql database and writing it into HDF5 using Pytables.I have 1 table and 5 variable arrays in one hdf5 file.The implementation of Hdf5 is not multithreaded or enabled for symmetric multi processing.I have rented about 10 computers for a day and trying to write them inorder to speed up my data handling.

As for as the postgresql table is concerned the overall record size is 140 million and I have 5 primary- foreign key referring tables.I am not using joins as it is not scalable

So for a single lookup i do 6 lookup without joins and write them into hdf5 format.
For each lookup i do 6 inserts into each of the table and its corresponding arrays.

The queries are really simple

```
select * from x.train where tr_id=1 (primary key & indexed)
select q_t from x.qt where q_id=2 (non-primary key but indexed)
```

(similarly five queries)

Each computer writes two hdf5 files and hence the total count comes around 20 files.

Some Calculations and statistics:

```
Total number of records : 14,37,00,000
Total number of records per file : 143700000/20 =71,85,000 
The total number of records in each file : 71,85,000 * 5 = 3,59,25,000
```

Current Postgresql database config :

My current Machine : 8GB RAM with i7 2nd generation Processor.

I made changes to the following to postgresql configuration file :
shared_buffers  : 2 GB
effective_cache_size : 4 GB

Note on current performance:

I have run it for about **ten hours** and the performance is as follows:
The total number of records written for each file is about **6,21,000 * 5 = 31,05,000**

The bottle neck is that i can only rent it for 10 hours per day (overnight) and if it processes in this speed it will take about **11 days** which is too high for my experiments.

Please suggest me on how to improve.
Questions:
1. Should i use Symmetric multi processing on those desktops(it has 2 cores with about 2 GB of RAM).In that case what is suggested or prefereable?
2. If i change my postgresql configuration file and increase the RAM will it enhance my process.
3. Should i use multi threading.. In that case any links or pointers would be of great help

Thanks
Sree aurovindh V

Comment: You are querying for something and iterating over the result to write some thing? In that case database may not be the bottle neck..

Comment: @jayan Hi, I am actually querying every time and writing the results into the hdf5 format. Can you please help me on optimising it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the following link

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CAC4BLaLCMuA6%3DDated_MsPKp5-F_EyKbrUkMWS4g_D7grwpVXQ%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=pytables-users

This might be helpful in understanding query efficiency.

Thanks

Comment: Care to summarize what the link mentioned?

Comment: link is dead. Could you summarize what solution you are using now? Thanks